# Является ли число симметричным

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано четырехзначное число. Определите, является ли его десятичная запись симметричной. Если число симметричное, то выведите 1, иначе выведите любое другое целое число. Число может иметь меньше четырех знаков, тогда нужно считать, что его десятичная запись дополняется слева нулями.

```
a = str(a)
if len(a) == 4:
    if a[1] == a[2] and a[0] == a[-1]:
        print('1')
    else:
        print('6')
if len(a) == 3:
    a = '0' + a
    if a[1] == a[2] and a[0] == a[-1]:
        print('1')
    else:
        print('6')
```

Код проваливается на одном из тестов. Ломаю голову уже 4 час

Comment: посмотрите что выведет ваш код если передать ему число состоящее из менее чем трех цифр ;)

Comment: но такой код как у вас лучше вообще не писать... `ns = str(n).zfill(4); print(1 if ns == ns[::-1] else 0)`

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу

Comment: Код проваливается на нуле.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так еще:

```
def symnum(a: int)-> int:
    return int(f"{a:04d}" == f"{a:04d}"[::-1])
```

```
print(symnum(111)) # 0
print(symnum(110)) # 1
print(symnum(1221))# 1
print(symnum(3131))# 0
print(symnum(5005))# 1
print(symnum(0))   # 1
```

Comment: элегантненько так ;)

Comment: @MaxU я вот тесты не проводил, но мне кажется f-строки с имплицитным преобразованием типов будут быстрее...

Comment: ну я же и говорю - лаконично и элегантно

Answer (score 0):

Меньше четырёх знаков это не только 3, но и 2, и даже 1.